# elq is not defined error in javascript

Tags: javascript, eloqua

I am trying to run the following javascript function. While running the below script, firebug spots an error. Below is the error message,

> ReferenceError: elq is not defined elq.dynamic(-57770, 5000,
>   'replace-me');

Code:

```
<div id="replace-me"> </div>    


<script type="text/javascript">
var _elqQ = _elqQ || [];
_elqQ.push(['elqSetSiteId', '5000']);
_elqQ.push(['elqTrackPageView']);

(function () {
    function async_load() {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;
        s.src = '//img.en25.com/i/elqCfg.min.js';
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async_load, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); 
})();
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.en25.com/i/elqDyn.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
elq.dynamic(-57770, 5000, 'replace-me');
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included elq library on your page? before calling the "dynamic" function?

Comment: Did you try call it in onload function?

Comment: _<script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.en25.com/i/elqDyn.min.js">
</script>_

Comment: While I appreciate that you are just trying to help, asking for clarifications is not really answering the question. You have enough rep to make comments - I believe that this should have been posted as one.

Comment: Yes, I did. I included elq libraray as below
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.en25.com/i/elqDyn.min.js">
</script>

Comment: Remove `;` from your declaration

Comment: No. May I know how to call it in onload function?

Comment: Do you have to include any other files? elqDyn.min.js refers to `_elqQ` which isn't defined there

Comment: `window.onload = function(){ elq.dynamic(-57770, 5000, 'replace-me'); }`

Comment: I have tried removing semicolon. it doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: I think you have to include another file. When I run the JS from the file in console, it complains about the undefined variable `_elqQ`. When I remove this variable, the code runs fine and `elq.dynamic()` is defined

Comment: @JozefDúc That should not matter. Not everything is fixed when putting it in the onload function ;)

Comment: I have included the another file too as shown in my description. (just updated). But still the same error

Answer (score 0):

[this pdf](http://www.proiv.com/Documentation%5Cpdf/Eloqua%20Async%20Tracking%20Scripts.pdf) (page 4) says like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _elqQ = _elqQ || [];
_elqQ.push(['elqSetSiteId', 'siteId']);
_elqQ.push(['elqTrackPageView']);
(function() {
function
async_load() {
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
s.async = true; 
s.src = '//img.en25.com/i/elqCfg.min.js';
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async_load, false);
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); })();
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://img.en25.com/i/elqDyn.min.js">
</script>

<!-- your code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
elq.dynamic(-57770, 5000, 'replace-me');
</script>
```